# Storing large response from gateway into database in efficient manner

Tags: go, pagination, architecture, microservices, large-data

We have service written in Go responsible for fetching the large transactions data from external entities/services. Our aim is to record all the data into the database. As the data is huge so the data is fetched in pages. Some pages can have 500 records and some can have 20000 records as well. What is the efficient way to store all the data into the postgres/mysql database.

We are fetching the data page by page and storing it in raw JSON format. We have another worker responsible for parsing each page of data and for recording we are again using one more worker which is recording the data in parallel.

All the process here is async is creating the challenge, we don't want to loose any data here.

Recording it page by page in sync manner is creating memory and cpu spike.

How can we solve the recording problem here? The aim here is to parse the data from the raw table and store it into the database efficiently.